# KeyError: 0, creating a table of polynomial regression values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, jupyter

So I am making a polynomial regression value table in pandas and have created a function to do so. Here is the function:

```
def poly_cor(df, power):
corr=df.corr()
index=[]
for i in range(0, len(corr[corr.columns])):
    index.append(corr.columns[i])
columns=[]
for i in range(0, len(corr[corr.columns])):
    columns.append(corr.columns[i])
for i in range(0, len(columns)):
    for j in range(0, len(index)):
        x=[]
        for k in range(0, len(df[columns[i]])):
            x.append(df[columns[i]][k])
        y=[]
        for k in range(0, len(df[index[j]])):
            y.append(df[columns[j]][k])
        mymodel = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 3))
        corr[columns[i]][index[j]]=r2_score(y, mymodel(x))
return corr
```

When I pass all my other data frames I don't come up with an error but when I pass one of my data frames the error appears. What could be the issue?

P.S. the ful error is below:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
> get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    3360             try:
> -> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)    3362             except KeyError as err:
> 
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in
> pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
> 
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in
> pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
> 
> pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
> 
> pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
> 
> KeyError: 0
> 
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
> 
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12436/797619603.py in <module>
> ----> 1 poly_corr=poly_cor(df_Ded, 3)
>       2 poly_corr
> 
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12436/2871017908.py in poly_cor(df,
> power)
>      11             x=[]
>      12             for k in range(0, len(df[columns[i]])):
> ---> 13                 x.append(df[columns[i]][k])
>      14             y=[]
>      15             for k in range(0, len(df[index[j]])):
> 
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in
> __getitem__(self, key)
>     940 
>     941         elif key_is_scalar:
> --> 942             return self._get_value(key)
>     943 
>     944         if is_hashable(key):
> 
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in
> _get_value(self, label, takeable)    1049     1050         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
> -> 1051         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)    1052         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)    1053 
> 
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
> get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    3361                 return
> self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)    3362             except KeyError
> as err:
> -> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err    3364     3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:
> 
> KeyError: 0
```

Comment: From the traceback it looks like `df[columns[i]]` is giving the problem, and `columns[i]` is the number `0`, rather than a valid column name.

Comment: The issue is this specific data frame is a sub frame of the main one, and that seemed to work and the other subframe however this one and another give this error so it is pretty confusing as to why it works for one and not the other.

Comment: len(corr[corr.columns]) Why are you using this? isn't len(corr.columns) fine?

Comment: I would suspect that your dataframe has a non-numeric index.

Comment: If it depends on the specific dataframe, there's no way we can help.  You can examine the frames, and identify what's different.  We can't.  Either you wrote this code, and know what it's supposed to be doing at each step, or you've borrowed it from somewhere else, and haven't a clue.  Look to the source of the code then.